# Find a character in a string gives wrong results

Tags: swift

I have an incoming string from Bluetooth which comes in chunks, at the end look like:

```
sentData1;
```

I want to print it only when I find the  `;` at the end, so :

```
    if let str = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
    {

               //data comes in chunks
               if (str.range(of: ";") == nil){dataIn+=str; return} //stop if not ;
               print("BLE:DATAIN:",dataIn ) //final
               dataIn=""
}
```

It will always print : `BLE:DATAIN: sent` .
I'v checked that the incoming data **is as expected**, the only way it will not stop half word is if I change the character to look for , to `@` or something else, then it will collect the whole word and not stop at `sent`.

Tried also with `NSNotfound` .

Comment: Are this code inside some loop?

Comment: Thanks, no its in a delegate function that being called every time you get input bluetooth data , and you get them in chunks of letters.

Comment: Side-note: You can replace long-winded `String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)` with `.utf8` (no kidding)

Comment: How? just `... , encoding: .utf8)`. – `encoding` expects `String.Encoding`. You are creating the encoding by its raw value which is the same as using the predefined `String.Encoding.utf8` value. The compiler can infer the type so you can even omit `String.Encoding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `if` condition you are checking that it contains `;` or not, but for that you need to add that string also, because you are ignoring the string when it contains the `;`. So try it this way:

```
if let data = characteristic.value,
   let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

      dataIn += str
      if (str.range(of: ";") == nil) {
          return
      }
      print("BLE:DATAIN:",dataIn ) //final
      dataIn=""
}
```

Comment: @Curnelious Have you try my solution once? Because when it contains `;` you are not adding it to string that is the reason you are not getting the `;` try like my answer once.

Comment: @Curnelious Welcome mate :), It happens some time :)

Comment: @Curnelious I think you got it now :)

Comment: @Curnelious In your case it is `Data1;` so `;` is with `Data` and you are ignoring the `Data` not only `;` if you want to confirm print the (str) always you will get batter idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if let str = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
{

           //data comes in chunks
           if (str.range(of: ";") != nil){dataIn+=str; return} //stop if not ;
           print("BLE:DATAIN:",dataIn ) //final
           dataIn=""
```

}

Comment: @Curnelious How come it won´t? Excuse me if I haven't understood you, but if what you want is to execute the if statement when the string contains ";" you should do it like I wrote above and not like you are trying.

Comment: @Curnelious Ok, now I understand your question. Still can you try what I wrote above?